# How to handle AWS API Gateway Authorization and architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway, go-fiber

I am trying to set up an API that multiple clients can use. Here are some of the requirements:

1. They have a throttled/rate-limited API key that is used to create a usage plan.
2. Their API key is associated with a database name to query from (using GoFiber)
3. A client can potentially have multiple databases (could use separate API Keys if needed)

This is what I was imagining:

https://path-to-api.com/v1/:database/ (this is the 'root' for the client's database)

My initial plan was to have API Gateway use an authorizer to make sure they have access to the database in the query paramater :database using some value. I'm totally fine checking inside GoFiber as well. I just didn't know if having it more 'monolithic' would be a bad thing.

pass the parameter to the GoFiber instance on Lambda.

this is the main route (keep in mind it isn't hooked up to lambda just yet) Think of it as more pseudo-code.

```
package gofiberApp

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func SetRoutes(app *fiber.App) {
    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": "Please choose a database",
        })
    })
    api := app.Group("/:database", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // Potentially run some checks here and connect to specific database
        return c.Next()
    })
    api.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "No action provided",
        })
    })
    api.Get("/outputs", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // Where we would run a SELECT query with c.Params()
        return c.SendString("Testing! 23")
    })

    api.Post("/generate", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // Where we would either perform the action with c.Params() or call another lambda
        return c.SendString("Where we generate the output")
    })
}
```

The end goal is to have an API that *all* clients can use with their respective databases and API keys, so I won't have to spin up another stage for each client.

client 1: https://path-to-gateway.com/v1/foo/outputs(with params) - API Key

client 2: https://path-to-gateway.com/v1/bar/generate(with params) - API Key

client 1: https://path-to-gateway.com/v1/baz/generate(with params) - API Key

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to choose the proper system design approach, and you don’t know where to put API key verification logic.

From what you described, it looks like you should use an authorizer in order to decouple to parts of your system and increase maintainability. But if you feel that in the future you may need to do more sophisticated database selection logic based on the api key value and other resources that are not available in your authorizer (even custom) but are available in GoFiber, you may want to choose the ‘monolithic’ approach.

However, you should also take into account the complexity of the system when deciding on the best approach. Extracting this DB selection logic outside the GoFiber may add some inconvenience during development, so no one can give you 100% correct answer without knowing all the input variables of your system.

Comment: I was worried that having all of that custom logic in fiber was a no no. I've never used api gateway like this and wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something abhorrent.